# Main title and subtitle does not plot correctly in a faceted ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, subtitle, page-title

[image][image]I am trying to plot a faceted gauge chart. The plot is OK except that the title and subtitle print in the first facet panel instead of the top. How can I correct that, I have tried "inherit.aes = FALSE" but I am getting:

```
 unused argument (inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

Here is the data and code that I have tried. Much thanks in advancef

```
library(showtext) 
library(tidyverse)


# add fonts

font_add_google(name = "Bebas Neue", family = "Bebas Neue")
showtext_auto()

#data 
 df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=5, ncol = 2))

names(df) <- c("variable", "percentage")
df$variable <- c("Carbohydrates", "Warming", "NGTnotPresent", "DrainNotPresent", "DrEaMing")
df$percentage <- c(0.67,0.33,0.86,0.78,0.58)

df <- df %>% mutate(group=ifelse(percentage <0.6, "red",
 ifelse(percentage>=0.6 & percentage<0.8, "orange","green")),
 label=paste0(percentage*100, "%"),
 title=dplyr::recode(variable, `Carbohydrates`="Preoperative\ncarbohydrate loading",
 `Warming`="Intraoperative\nwarming",
 `NGTnotPresent`="\nPatients without a\nnasogastric tube\non arrival in recovery",
 `DrainNotPresent`="\nPatients without an\nabdominal drain\non arrival in recovery",
 `DrEaMing`="Patients DrEaMing on\npostoperative day 1"))

title <- "pomVLAD risk-adjustment model"
subtitle <- 'The model is being used to produce a variable life-adjusted display plot for each of the 10 pilot hospitals showing their expected against observed postoperative morbidity outcomes' %>% 
      str_wrap(width = 50)
caption <- "Data: pomVLAD | Viz: @stepminer2"

#plot 
gg<- ggplot(df, aes(fill = group, ymax = percentage, ymin = 0, xmax = 2, xmin = 1)) +
 geom_rect(aes(ymax=1, ymin=0, xmax=2, xmin=1), fill ="#ece8bd") +
 geom_rect() + 
 coord_polar(theta = "y",start=-pi/2) + xlim(c(0, 2)) + ylim(c(0,2)) +
 geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = label, colour=group), size=25.5, family=""Bebas Neuel"", face= "bold") +
 geom_text(aes(x=1.5, y=1.5, label=title), family=""Bebas Neuel"", size=14.2, color="black") + 
 facet_wrap(~title, ncol = 5) +
 theme_void() +
 scale_fill_manual(values = c("red"="#C9146C", "orange"="#DA9112", "green"="#129188")) +
 scale_colour_manual(values = c("red"="#C9146C", "orange"="#DA9112", "green"="#129188")) +
 theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
 strip.text.x = element_blank()
 
 ) +
 guides(fill=FALSE) +
 guides(colour=FALSE)


gg+
 labs(
  title = title,
  subtitle = subtitle,
  caption = caption)+
 theme(
  plot.title = element_text(family = "Bebas Neue", size = 50, colour = "black",
                            margin = margin(t = 20, b = 10),  inherit.aes = FALSE),
  plot.subtitle = element_text(family = "Bebas Neue", size = 30, colour = "black",
                               margin = margin(b = 20), inherit.aes = FALSE),
  plot.caption = element_text(color = "black", size = 20, hjust = 0.5)
   )
```

Comment: Your code example is not a minimal reproducible code example. First of all, it contains errors that prevent it from running and lots of code that has nothing to do with the actual problem. Frequently simplifying the code will let one find the answer by oneself.  As is, your question and my answer will not be useful to others. Please, edit the code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple: you are wraping the caption text to a width of 50 characters with `str_wrap(width = 50)`. Change `50` into a bigger number.

Comment: Thanks, Pedro, it looks more like what I was expecting.